# run a socket from a windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, service

I need to run a socket which is always listening as a windows service.
I am doing this in C#

I have an executable version of my program which uses the following code

```
Console.WriteLine("sock1");
                SynchronousSocketListener synchronousSocketListener = new SynchronousSocketListener();
            synchronousSocketListener.StartListening();

            Console.WriteLine("sock2");
```

This code works when running the program as an executable but does not work when running as a service because the socket listener never returns, and thus blocks the service from starting. ("sock2" never prints)

I tried the following code to run the socket listener asynchronously (this was done in the executable version of the program not the servicce version which is why there is a main method rather than an onStart method.

```
class Program
{

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("sock1");
        Program a = new Program();
        var blah = a.startSocketListenerAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("sock2");

        Thread.sleep(1000000);
        return 0;
    }

    public async Task<string> startSocketListenerAsync()
    {
        SynchronousSocketListener synchronousSocketListener = new SynchronousSocketListener();
        await Task.Run( ()  => synchronousSocketListener.StartListening() );

        return "hello world";

    }
```

}

This runs the socket listener asynchronously (sock2 prints) if i set a long enough sleep period, the problem is this program terminates as soon as the main thread finishes (closing the sockets thread with it)

How can I get this to work as a service?

Answer (score 0):

It seams i dont need to do anything
when running as a service it remains active in the background